# How to shuffle tiny spheres inside a big sphere in a pythonic way?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, random, shuffle

I have a list of spheres with some known characteristics (ids, radii, masses, and positions) with *ids*, *radii*, and *masses* being *1D arrays* with shape (511, ) and *positions* being *3D array* with shape (511, 3) inside some big spherical volume with known center, *(0, 0, 0)* and radius, *distance_max*.

```
hal_ids_data = np.array([19895, 19896, ..., 24249])                   
hal_radiuss_data = np.array([1.047, 1.078, ..., 3.263])                 
hal_masss_data = np.array([2.427e+06, 8.268e+06, ..., 8.954e+07]     
hal_positions_data = np.array([np.array([-33.78, 10.4, 33.83]), np.array([-33.61, 6.34, 35.64]), ..., np.array([-0.4014, 4.121, 33.05])])
```

I would like to randomly place these tiny spheres throughout the volume within the big sphere while keeping their individual characteristics intact meaning only their positions need to be shuffled *subject to two constraints shown below*.

```
for hal_id, hal_position, hal_radius, hal_mass in zip(hal_ids_data, hal_positions_data, hal_radiuss_data, hal_masss_data):

    # check if 1) any one of the small spheres are above some mass threshold AND 2) inside the big sphere
    if ((np.sqrt(pow(hal_position[0], 2)+pow(hal_position[1], 2)+pow(hal_position[2], 2)) < distance_max) and (log10(hal_mass)>=1e8)):

        # if so, then do the following stuff down here but to the shuffled populations of small spheres meeting the conditions above rather than to the original population
```

What is the fastest and shortest way to shuffle my spheres *under the last `if statement` before doing some stuff on them*? (I do need my original population info though for later use so I cannot disregard it)

Comment: This is likely cleaner/easier if you stay away from `pandas`.  Suggest you update the post with some examples of your raw data, specifically the variable holding the "big sphere" and the list with the small spheres.  Also, if you are changing the position, the only data left to retain is the radius of each small sphere, right?  So the original position is a throw-away?

Comment: THe only algorithm I could think about is POisson spheres sampling, http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.84.5558&rep=rep1&type=pdf Maybe you could find something useful there

Comment: Could you add a small example of your data to work with?

Comment: It would be truly mindful to see positive/negative feedbacks that are constructive than simply "disliking" a post. My understanding is that we must not treat this environment like fb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to compute your constraints in a vectorized format (which is very efficient in numpy) instead of using a for loop. Then generate an array of indexes that match your constraints, and then shuffle those indexes.

So using your example data above:

```py
import numpy as np

distance_max = 49 #I chose this so that we have some matching items

hal_ids_data = np.array([19895, 19896, 24249])                   
hal_radius_data = np.array([1.047, 1.078, 3.263])                 
hal_mass_data = np.array([2.427e+06, 8.268e+06, 8.954e+07])     
hal_positions_data = np.array([np.array([-33.78, 10.4, 33.83]), np.array([-33.61, 6.34, 35.64]), np.array([-0.4014, 4.121, 33.05])])

# Compute the conditions for every sphere at the same time instead of for loop
within_max = np.sqrt(pow(hal_positions_data[:,0],2) + pow(hal_positions_data[:,1],2) + pow(hal_positions_data[:,2],2)) < distance_max
mass_contraint = np.log10(hal_mass_data) >= 1 #I chose this so that we have some matching items
matched_spheres = within_max & mass_contraint

# Get indexes of matching spheres
idx = np.where(matched_spheres)[0] # create array of indexes
np.random.shuffle(idx) #shuffle array of indexes in place

# Generate shuffled data by applying the idx to the original arrays and saving to new 's_' arrays
s_hal_ids_data = hal_ids_data[idx]
s_hal_radius_data = hal_radius_data[idx]
s_hal_mass_data = hal_mass_data[idx]
s_hal_positions_data = hal_positions_data[idx]

# Do stuff with shuffled population of small spheres
```